# How to run Gem5 system emulation with Golang program

Tags: go, system, gem5, x86-emulation

I am trying to run Gem5 system emulation with a binary I compiled from a Golang program. I am using X86 O3CPU and classic memory. However, I have to launch the same process on 3 cpus to have the system emulation set up. Otherwise I will receive error: fail to create new OS thread. I try to set the GOMAXPROCS to 1 or MAXTHREADS to 1. Neither of them solve this problem.

But even if i run the binary with 3 cpu. I still might receive error:

wirep: p->m=824633877504(2) p->status=1
fatal error: wirep: invalid p state

after many hours of emulation. Does anyone have experience with running Gem5 with Golang?